# php não atualiza cadastro no bd mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Eu estou tentando fazer atualização no banco de dados, ele retorna a mensagem de que foi feita a atualização, entretanto, ao ver no banco de dados, a atualização não foi feita.

**O que deveria acontecer:**

Ao clicar no botão salvar, os campos modificados deveriam ser alterados no registro.

**O que está acontecendo:**

Quando tento alterar o registro aparece a msg de "salvo com sucesso" e volta pra página anterior, como deveria acontecer. Mas olhando pelo phpMyAdmin, o registro continua inalterado

**Todo o Código**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$data = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$acordo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'acordo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$valor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valor', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$divida = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'divida', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


//echo " data " . $data . " - acordo " . $acordo . " - valor " . $valor . " - divida " . $divida  . " - id " . $id;

$atualizacao_data = $_SESSION['atualiza_Pcl-data'];
$atualizacao_divida = $_SESSION['atualiza_Pcl-divida'];
$atualizacao_acordo = $_SESSION['atualiza_Pcl-acordo'];
$atualizacao_valor = $_SESSION['atualiza_Pcl-valor'];
$mudanca = '';
$user = 'gustavo';

/* rastreio */
if ($atualizacao_data != $data) {
    $mudanca = 'DATA => antes - ' . $atualizacao_data . ' | depois - ' . $data . '<br>';
}

if ($atualizacao_divida != $divida) {
    $mudanca = $mudanca . 'DIVIDA => antes - ' . $atualizacao_divida . ' | depois - ' . $divida . '<br>';
}

if ($atualizacao_acordo != $acordo) {
    $mudanca = $mudanca . 'ACORDO => antes - ' . $atualizacao_acordo . ' | depois - ' . $acordo . '<br>';
}

if ($atualizacao_valor != $valor) {
    $mudanca = $mudanca . 'VALOR => antes - ' . $atualizacao_valor . ' | depois - ' . $valor;
}

//echo $mudanca;

/* cadastro rastreio */

$cad_auteracao = "UPDATE parcelamento set aut_por='$user',
                                            data_aut=now,
                                            auteracao='$mudanca',
                                            WHERE id='$id'";
$conect= mysqli_query($conn, $cad_auteracao);

/* cadastro atualização */

$atualiza = "UPDATE parcelamento SET datavenc='$data',
                                        divida='$divida',
                                        acordo='$acordo',
                                        valorpcl'='$valor'
                                        WHERE id='$id'";

$resul_atualiza = mysqli_query($conn, $atualiza);

echo $atualiza;

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msgAtualiza_pcl'] = "<p style='color:green;'>Usuário editado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: ../edit-parcela.php?id=$id"); 
}else{
    $_SESSION['msgAtualiza_pcl'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Usuário não foi editado!</p>";
    header("Location: ../edit-parcela.php?id=$id");
}

?>
```

Já testei todas as variaveis, estão todas funcionando como deveriam. Estão recebendo os valores, entretanto não está sendo feita a atualização.
Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

A unica parte na qual esta dando errado é na parte do codigo:

**Trecho no qual está com o problema**

```
$atualiza = "UPDATE parcelamento SET datavenc='$data', divida='$divida', acordo='$acordo', valorpcl'='$valor' WHERE id='$id'";

$resul_atualiza = mysqli_query($conn, $atualiza);
```

A atualização (UPDATE) não ta atualizando. Ele apenas retorna que foi atulizado, mas ao consultar o BD, a atualização não foi feita.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tem erros no seus SQL's.

Os dois não estão sendo executados.

No primeiro tem uma virgula antes do WHERE e a função now precisa de parenteses NOW().

No segundo tem uma aspas simples depois do campo "valorpcl" e antes do igual (=).

E faltou um pouquinho de boas praticas. Quando usar variaveis dentro de strings, coloca entre {chaves}.

```
$cad_auteracao = "
    UPDATE parcelamento 
    SET 
        data_aut = NOW(),
        aut_por = '{$user}',
        auteracao = '{$mudanca}'
    
    WHERE id='{$id}'
";

/**************************************************/


$atualiza = "
    UPDATE parcelamento 
    SET 
        datavenc = '{$data}',
        divida = '{$divida}',
        acordo = '{$acordo}',
        valorpcl = '{$valor}'
    
    WHERE id = '{$id}'
";
```

Comment: Olá meu amigo. Sim, resolveu meu problema. O que acho engraçado é que antes, dessa forma funcionava, e foi o que professores me ensinaram.  Mas muito obrigado. Fiz as alterações que voce disse e em ambas as partes, o UPTADE funcionou. 

Onde posso consultar mais sobre como fazer de forma certa?

Comment: Qualquer duvisa sobre mysql vc pode consultar na documentação no site deles. Segue a pagina de select por exemplo. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: É irônica uma resposta cita boas práticas ensinar fazer errado só porque funciona. è por isso que tem tanta gente fazendo errado, a pessoa só quer que outra diga como funcionar, mesmo que errado.

Comment: Já que mencionou as "boas práticas", então seria melhor dizer que **não é uma boa ideia concatenar os valores diretamente na query**, pois isso deixa a aplicação vulnerável a ataques de [SQL injection](/q/100729/112052). Saiba mais [aqui](/q/3864/112052) e [aqui](/q/256111/112052). (cc @Guest3rr067)

Comment: Então pessoal, hoje notei que minha duvida esta gerando repercução. Confesso que sou iniciante na area, e com cursinhos que consegui comprar, apredi da forma descrita acima. Fico imensamente grato por estarem abrindo meus olhos para o risco que meu codigo corre. 
Se puderem me guiar nessa jornada, ficarei imensamente grato.